# jQuery click event problem iPhone, Safari iPad

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, ipad, safari

My site seems to function in most browsers but in the Mac series (iPhone etc).

Most of the features work but when it comes to a select section using images as the target the selection isn't working.

I don't have an iPhone to test but according to feedback - on the page (linked to below) the initial icon click brings up the modal window with the icons to choose - it is that selection that doesn't work.

An example of the code for this icon selection is:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('#cd').click(function() {
jQuery('#cd').fadeTo('fast',1);
    jQuery('#dvd').fadeTo('fast', .25, function() {
        jQuery('input[name=frmmedia]').val(1);
            jQuery('#next').show();
});
});
});
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('#dvd').click(function() {
    jQuery('#dvd').fadeTo('fast',1);
        jQuery('#cd').fadeTo('fast', .25, function() {
            jQuery('input[name=frmmedia]').val(2);
                jQuery('#next').show();
 });
});
});
```

The php code/page that contains the icons in this example is:

```
 <div id="selmodule">
 <div id="optionholder"><img src="../img/pricemodules/dvd.jpg" alt="dvd" name="dvd" width="199" height="85" class="hoverswap" id="dvd" /><img src="../img/pricemodules/cd.jpg"   alt="compact disc" name="cd" width="212" height="85" class="hoverswap" id="cd" />
</div>
     </div>
<br />
<br />
<h3>Changing this option <br/>will reset the packaging options</h3>

 <form action="sess-set-reset.php" method="get" id="firstform" >
<input name="frmmedia" type="hidden"  id="frmmedia" value="" />
    <div id="next"><input type="image" name="Submit" value="Next" src="../img/page-elements/confirm.jpg"/>
   </div> 
   </form>
```

The code that opens the above PHP page is this (which DOES work on iPhone)

```
//----media elements-----------------------------------------------------
jQuery(function (jQuery) {
jQuery('.media').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#contentholder').load("media.php");
    jQuery("#contentholder").modal({
        onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
                dialog.data.hide();
                dialog.container.fadeIn('fast', function () {
                    dialog.data.slideDown('fast');
                });
            });
        }
    });
})
})
```

The actual page is the 'pricing' page here: 
[discburner](http://www.discburner.co.uk/cd-duplication/pricing/sess-set-reset.php?frmmedia=1)
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In the Apple dev tools' simulator, it seems to work fine on an iPhone 4 (iOS v4.0) and on an iPad (iOS v3.2). Perhaps you've fixed it by now? Or maybe I'm trying the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can / should install a tool such as [iPhoney](http://www.marketcircle.com/iphoney/) for Mac, or [iBBDemo2](http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662) for Windows.. or ideally, the [Xcode /iPhone SDK](http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/test-your-website-across-ios-devices-using-the-iphone-simulator/) if you're on a Mac -  and test all your sites yourself in these  emulated environments.  You can also find several online MobileSafari "simulators.  [Here](http://www.iphonepreviewer.com/moonshell/), or [Here](http://www.testiphone.com/), for example.  Touch events can be dicey, and as of this writing, they are not all resolved in the standard jQuery libs.  If you can't work through this issue, an interesting, up-and-coming solution can be found with the [jQuery "Mobile" project](http://jquerymobile.com/), now in beta.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not have a browsable file system like a computer, so even if Safari supported file uploads, you would not be able to browse to the file to select it.

This is for security reasons as every iOS app runs in a sandbox and has no access to other apps data.

You can download or write App so as to upload the Photos and Videos..